# How can I add placeholders to password fields in python django forms?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add placeholders to my django form fields, but they only seem to be working for the username and email fields and not for the password fields. I have already tried to use `TextInput` or a widgets dictionary and `PasswordInput` instead of `TextInput`, but both didn't work for me. Could someone please help me?

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm): 
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2'
        ]
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Username',
                }),
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Email'
                }),
            'password1': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Password'}),
            'password2': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Confirm Password'
                })
        }
```

Comment: Do the `password1` and `password2` fields actually exist on the `User` base model?

Comment: Yes please. they work perfectly at the front end

Comment: I believe your problem is because the `password1` and `password2` fields **do not** actually exist on the base `User` model.  Why did you say that they did?

Comment: I thought since it was rendered on my signup template, it existed. Please forgive me. I am new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the following before and it works. It is just slightly different than what you are posting as I am using the widget inside of the form.CharField

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'placeholder' : 'Your username',
    }))
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Your email',
    }))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Your Password',
    }))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Repeat Password',
    }))
```